# Why does not work the addition / removal of elements in “LocalStorage”?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I want to add: the name, phone and mail of the user in the `localStorage` using the method: `addContact()` and with the data that is there in `localStorage`, I create the table using the method `show()`.

Also does not happen  delete the contact, I'm trying to do with the method: `deleteContact(e)`.

- When I add contact I receive the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`
- When I deleting  I    receive the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined`

**Help me fix that**

```js
//Product Creation Class
class LocalStorage {
    constructor(name, phone, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;

    }
}
// Сlass where products are recorded
class Book {
    constructor() {

        this.products = [];
        this.name = document.getElementById("name");
        this.phone = document.getElementById("phone");
        this.email = document.getElementById("email");
        this.buttAdd = document.getElementById("add");
        this.book = document.getElementById("addBook");
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addContact() {
        let isNull = this.name.value != '' && this.phone.value != '' && this.email.value != '';
        if (isNull) {
            let obj = new LocalStorage(this.name.value, this.phone.value, this.email.value);
            this.products.push(obj);
            localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(this.products);
            this.show();
        }
    }

    //method for remove product by name
    deleteContact(e) {
        if (e.target.className === "delbutton") {
            let remID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            this.products.splice(remID, 1);
            localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(this.products);
            this.show();
        }
    }

    // method to draw the table with product property (
    // name, phone, email)
    show() {
        if (localStorage['addbook'] === undefined) {
            localStorage['addbook'] = '';
        } else {
            this.products = JSON.parse(localStorage['addbook']);

            this.book.innerHTML = '';
            for (let e in this.products) {
                let table = `          <table id="shop" class="entry">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <th id="filter">Phone:</th>
                    <th>Email:</th>
                    <th class="dels"></th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="data">
                <td>${this.products[e].name}</td>
                <td>${this.products[e].phone}</td>
                <td>${this.products[e].email}</td>
                <td class="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="' + e + '">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
            </table>`;
                this.book.innerHTML += table;
            }
        }

    }

    OperationsWithContacts() {
        // add new product by click
        this.buttAdd.addEventListener('click', this.addContact);
        // delete product by name after click
        this.book.addEventListener('click', this.deleteContact);
        console.log(this.products);
    }
}

let shop = new Book();
shop.show();
shop.OperationsWithContacts();
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
    <div class="add-product">
        <h1>Add product</h1>
        <form name="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="phone">Price of product</label>
            <input type="number" id="phone" class="input-product">
            <label for="email">Count of product</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="input-product">
            <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="product-table">
        <h2>Address book</h2>
        <div id="delete-form">
            <label for="name-delete">Search product by name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
        </div>
        <div id="addBook"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: `localStorage['addbook'] = '';` `JSON.parse()` does not work on empty strings.

Comment: In this line, I render an empty array when the condition is fulfilled and it works. Problem in another

Comment: Call `show()` twice in a row without having `localStorage['addbook']` set and you will see it fail, since you only check it on `undefined`.

Comment: thanks, now I saw that problem, can you tell me what to fix to make the code work?

Comment: Were you able to find your mistakes? Would be kinda interesting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obivous issue I see is that `this` in both your functions `addContact()` and `deleteContact()` represents a `button`-HTML-Element and not the class you think it does.

Just change the code a bit and you will see:
//method for adding a product

```
addContact() {
    console.log('addContact()', this);

    let isNull = this.name.value != '' && this.phone.value != '' && this.email.value != '';
    if (isNull) {
        let obj = new LocalStorage(this.name.value, this.phone.value, this.email.value);
        this.products.push(obj);
        localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(this.products);
        this.show();
    }
}
```

So you might want to change your bind from:

`document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', this.addContact);`

to

`document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', this.addContact.bind(this));`

to properly reuse the `this` shortcut.

### Edit:

```js
//Product Creation Class
//REM: Not the best name choice here.. localStorage <> LocalStorage
class LocalStorage{
  constructor(name, phone, email){
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email
  }
};

//Сlass where products are recorded
class Book{
  constructor(){
    this.products = [];
    this.name = document.getElementById("name");
    this.phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    this.email = document.getElementById("email");
    this.buttAdd = document.getElementById("add");
    this.book = document.getElementById("addBook")
  };

  //method for adding a product
  addContact(){
    let isNull = this.name.value != '' && this.phone.value != '' && this.email.value != '';
    if(isNull){
      let obj = new LocalStorage(this.name.value, this.phone.value, this.email.value);
      this.products.push(obj);
      localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(this.products);
      this.show();
    }
  };

  //method for remove product by name
  deleteContact(e) {
    if(e.target.className === "delbutton"){
      let remID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
      this.products.splice(remID, 1);
      localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(this.products);
      this.show();
    }
  };

  //method to draw the table with product property (
  //name, phone, email)
  show(){
    if(localStorage['addbook'] === undefined) {
      //REM: An empty string is no valid JSON to be serialised
      localStorage['addbook'] = '[]'
    }
    else{
      this.products = JSON.parse(localStorage['addbook']);
      this.book.innerHTML = '';

      for(let e in this.products){
        let table = `          <table id="shop" class="entry">
          <tr>
          <th>Name:</th>
          <th id="filter">Phone:</th>
          <th>Email:</th>
          <th class="dels"></th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
          <tr class="data">
          <td>${this.products[e].name}</td>
          <td>${this.products[e].phone}</td>
          <td>${this.products[e].email}</td>
          <td class="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="' + e + '">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>`;

        this.book.innerHTML += table;
      }
    }
  };

  OperationsWithContacts(){
    // add new product by click
    this.buttAdd.addEventListener('click', this.addContact.bind(this));

    // delete product by name after click
    this.book.addEventListener('click', this.deleteContact.bind(this));
    console.log(this.products);
  }
};

;window.onload = function(){
  let shop = new Book();
  shop.show();
  shop.OperationsWithContacts()
};
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
  <div class="add-product">
    <h1>Add product</h1>
    <form name="addForm">
      <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
      <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
      <label for="phone">Price of product</label>
      <input type="number" id="phone" class="input-product">
      <label for="email">Count of product</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="input-product">
      <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="product-table">
    <h2>Address book</h2>
    <div id="delete-form">
      <label for="name-delete">Search product by name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
    </div>
    <div id="addBook"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code for your example, but still this error:  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: @Igor Shvets: Works fine for me. Can add and delete products. The error you mentioned sounds exactly like the binding error, since a HTML-Button does not have a `phone` property and thus no `value` on it.

Comment: Maybe the HTML-Elements from `getElementById()` dont exist.